# Sorting related models in a Yii findByPk()

Tags: php, yii

Using the Yii Framework, How can I sort the related model modifiervalues by "sortorder ASC, name ASC"? I have tried `order->('modifiervalues.sortorder ASC, modifiervalues.name ASC')` to no avail

```
<?php
    $item = Item::model()
    ->with("modifiergroups.modifiervalues")
    ->findByPk($id);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$item = Item::model()
        ->with('modifiergroups')
        ->find(array(
                'condition'=>'id = :id',
                'params'=>array('id'=>$id),
                'order'=>'modifiervalues.sortorder ASC, modifiervalues.name ASC'
              )
         );
```

or (I haven't actually tried this one, but it should work just the same)

```
$item = Item::model()
        ->with(array('modifiergroups'=>array('order'=>'modifiervalues.sortorder ASC, modifiervalues.name ASC')))
        ->findByPk($id));
```

Notes:

- if you give `with` only a field, I don't think you can order by another field. You should give `with` the name of the relation.
- [CActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord/) doesn't have an `order` method

Comment: Thanks Ors! I had to make a few modifications to get it working, I added modifiergroups to the first array key, and removed the extra ) at the end. $item = Item::model()
        ->with(array('modifiergroups.modifiervalues'=>array('order'=>'modifiervalues.sortorder ASC, modifiervalues.name ASC')))
        ->findByPk($id);

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $item = Item::model()
    ->with(array('modifiergroups'=>array('order'=>'modifiervalues.sortorder ASC, modifiervalues.name ASC')))
    ->findByPk($id));
?>
```

You need to add base relation name in order also.
Try this.

Comment: Item does not have the 'order' method even after adding the base relation. I got it working with the answer above but thanks!